# How to Focus on TextInput on click of button in react native

Tags: typescript, react-hooks, react-native, react-native-ios

I am trying to set focus on `TextInput` when I click on edit button, but I am getting error.

Below is my code:

```
const MyProfileScreen = (props: any) => {
    const refsFocus = useRef(null);
    return (
        <>
            <View>
                <TextInput
                    placeholder={'editable test'}
                    placeholderTextColor={'red'}
                    style={{color: 'red'}}
                    ref={refsFocus}
                />
            </View>
            <TouchableOpacity
                onPress={()=> { refsFocus.current.focus();} }
                >
                <Text>Edit text input</Text>
            </TouchableOpacity>
        </>
    );
};
```

But I am getting error on `onPress={()=> { refsFocus.current.focus()} }`

Error Message:

`Object is possibly 'null'`

`const refsFocus: React.MutableRefObject<null>`

I am not able to figure out what I am doing wrong

Answer (score 0):

You should assign useRef hook to Textinput ref like this

```
ref={refsFocus}
```

And then in onPress method you should call it like this

```
onPress={()=> { refsFocus.current.focus()} }
```

Also remove that semicolon from onPress arrow function.

Comment: `Object is possibly 'null'`, getting this error on `refsFocus.current`